# How to in calculate percentages in swift?

Tags: swift

I am creating an expense ios application. I am using a Progress View to display how much income the user has left. So for example, if the user puts $100 income, and $30 expense, I'd like the bar to be 70% full. How do I calculate this?

I had originally put

`let fractionalProgress = Float(expenseFloat!)/Float(balanceFloat!)`

but this doesn't return the right value needed.

Comment: What do you mean by "but this doesn't return the right value needed"? It should return a value between 0.0 and 1.0. If you would like to show it as percentage you need to use NumberFormatter

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: If I put in $100 in income, and $50 in expenses, it does 100/50 and gives me 2.0

Comment: But that's a correct result. You're finding the ratio of income to expenses though (2.0 times greater or 200%). You need `e/i*100`.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils No, an income of 100 and expenses of 50 means the remaining percent is 0.5 or 50%.

Comment: @maddy, of course, misread the comment as they believe 100/50 != 2.

Answer (score 13):

The formula in your question is correct if you want to know the percentage spent so far.

The percent remaining formula is "remaining balance" / "original balance".

And of course "remaining balance" is "original balance" - "total of expenses".

```
let fractionalProgress = (balanceFloat - expenseFloat) / balanceFloat
```

where `balanceFloat` is the original balance and `expenseFloat` is the total expenses.

In your example with a `balanceFloat` of `100` and an `expenseFloat` of `30` this gives `(100 - 30) / 100` which is `0.7`.

Of course you would multiple this result by 100 if you wish to show a percentage. Better yet, use a `NumberFormatter` setup with a `.percent` style.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You should implement this answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 13):

We can calculate **percentage** in **swift** as below:

```
//Calucate percentage based on given values
public func calculatePercentage(value:Double,percentageVal:Double)->Double{
    let val = value * percentageVal
    return val / 100.0
}
```

We can use this function like:

```
 let value = calculatePercentage(value: 500,percentageVal: 20)
 print(value)
```

Output will be:

**100**

Comment: what if I pass value 3 and percentageVal 1, then it will not return in percentage form, result will be in double like 0.03

Comment: why this answer has any upvotes when it is not relevant to question. Here percentage value is passed in function while question is how to calculate percentage in first place?